# How do I adjust the image size in the QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to adjust the image size in the QTableWidget.

But it is size comes out small. (The part that looks like an "이미지")

[image]

Below is the original image.

[image]

Please help me by referring to the code below.

Thanks.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

imgPath = "D:\Image\Image1.png"
self.tableWidget1 = QTableWidget(self.tab1)
self.tableWidget1.setRowCount(30)
self.tableWidget1.setColumnCount(3)
self.tableWidget1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(setNameList)
self.tableWidget1.resize(1824, 760)
self.tableWidget1.move(0, 0)
self.tableWidget1.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem(QIcon(QPixmap(imgPath).scaled(QSize(1280, 640), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)), ''))
```

Comment: You could show what you get, and what you want to get.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I added a picture.

Comment: the image you place has a blank border as a background? You could place one of those images, in addition to placing another image that describes what you want to obtain.

Comment: I also added the original of the Image.

Comment: According to what I see the error is caused because it has white edges, you could crop the image to show only the main object

Comment: I tired the image with no white edges and the same result came out.

Comment: Then better show me that cropped image so as not to confuse people.

Comment: Oh Sorry.. I uploaded the image again. Thanks